# Python. Join specific lines on 1 line

Tags: python, lines, string-parsing, reorganize

Let's say I have this file:

```
1
17:02,111
Problem report related to
router

2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems

3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk
now due to compromised data
```

I want this output:

```
1
17:02,111
Problem report related to router

2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems

3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk now due to compromised data
```

Been trying in bash and got to a kind of close solution but I don't know how to carry this out on Python.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## If you want to remove the extea lines :

For this aim you can check 2 condition for each like one if the line don't followed by an empty  new line, or line should precede by a line that match with following regex `^\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s$`.

So for access to next line in each iteration you can create one file object from your main file object with the name `temp` using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and apply the `next` function on it. and use `re.match` to match the regex.

```
from itertools import tee
import re
with open('ex.txt') as f,open('new.txt','w') as out:
    temp,f=tee(f)
    next(temp)
    try:
        for line in f:
            if next(temp) !='\n' or re.match(r'^\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s$',pre):
                out.write(line)
            pre=line
    except :
        pass
```

result :

```
1
17:02,111
Problem report related to

2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems

3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk
```

---

## If you want to concatenate the rest to third line :

And if you want to concatenate the rest lines after third line to third line you can use following regex to find all blocks that followed by `\n\n` or the end of file (`$`) :

```
r"(.*?)(?=\n\n|$)"
```

then split your blocks based on the line that in in a date format and write the parts to your output file, but note that you need to replace the new lines within 3rd part with space  :

ex.txt:

```
1
17:02,111
Problem report related to
router
another line


2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems

3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk
now due to compromised data
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

Demo :

```
def splitter(s):
    for x in re.finditer(r"(.*?)(?=\n\n|$)", s,re.DOTALL):
          g=x.group(0)
          if g:
            yield g

import re
with open('ex.txt') as f,open('new.txt','w') as out:
    for block in splitter(f.read()):
        first,second,third= re.split(r'(\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\n)',block)
        out.write(first+second+third.replace('\n',' '))
```

result :

```
1
17:02,111
Problem report related to router another line
2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems
3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk now due to compromised data line 5 line 6 line 7
```

## *Note* :

In this answer the `splitter` function returns a generator that is very efficient when you are dealing with huge files and refuse of storing unusable lines in memory.

Comment: @aDoN I updated the answer with an approach using file also in that case you don't need to use `cat` and `pip`.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong isn't your output wrong the third lines are removed but he wants it to be appended to second right

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yeah thanks for reminding that seem i missed that or OP has edited the question!

Comment: Nice answer though :p

Comment: That solution work wonders but I have a doubt:

What does `(.*?)` do¿? I mean here `"(.*?)(?=\n\n|$)"` because I guess x.group(0) are the ones that match `\n\n|$`

Thanks

Comment: @aDoN `(?=)` is a positive look ahead that for `(.*?)(?=\n\n|$)` will match any thing `(.*?)` that followed by 2 new line character or the end of your string `(?=\n\n|$)`!

Comment: I am not sure why not `(*)(?=\n\n|$)` for example (I know it doesn't work but don't know why), don't understand the `?` at the end nor the `.` at the beginning

Comment: because `*` actually Matches 0 or more of the preceding token.and you need to specify a token for it, in this case we used  dot `.` that will match any character!

Comment: So what about `?` and `*` ? Thank you.

Totally based on your solution I got to this:

`import sys
import re  

text = sys.stdin.read()  
text_splitted = re.split(r'\n\n|$', text)  


for block in text_splitted:  
    
    first,second,third = re.split(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\n)',block)  
    print first,second,third.replace('\n',' ')+'\n'`

Comment: @aDoN Its none greedy read more here http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution

Answer (score 2):

This works well if and only if the file as per your given sample

**Note:**

`There may be a faster way if  regex is used and it might also be simpler` but wanted to do it in a logical way

**Code:**

```
inp=open("output.txt","r")
inp=inp.read().split("\n")
print inp
tempString=""
output=[]
w=0

for s in inp:
    if s:
        if any(c.isalpha() for c in s):
            tempString=tempString+" "+s
        else:
            w=0
            if tempString:
                output.append(tempString.strip())
                tempString=""
            output.append(s)       

    else:
        if tempString:
            output.append(tempString.strip())
            tempString=""
        output.append(" ")
if tempString:
    output.append(tempString.strip())


print "\n".join(output)
out=open("newoutput.txt","w")
out.write("\n".join(output))
out.close()
```

**Input:**

```
1
17:02,111
Problem report related to
2 router

2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems

3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk
now due to compromised data

4
17:02,111
Problem report related to
router
```

**output:**

```
1
17:02,111
Problem report related to 2 router

2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems

3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk now due to compromised data

4
17:02,111
Problem report related to router
```

Comment: Awesome solution, any idea if the text is:

Problem report related to 2 routers and "2" is the beginning of the newline¿?

Comment: so you are saying the line may contain 2 routers right

Comment: great solution too yeah

Answer (score 1):

```
x="""1
17:02,111
Problem report related to
router

2
17:05,223
Restarting the systems

3
18:02,444
Must erase hard disk
now due to compromised data
or something"""
def repl(matchobj):
    ll=matchobj.group().split("\n")
    return "\n".join(ll[:3])+" "+" ".join(ll[3:])
print re.sub(r"\b\d+\n\d+:\d+,\d+\b[\s\S]*?(?=\n{2}|$)",repl,x)
```

You can use `re.sub` with your own custom replacement feature.